# have a log file that I would like to break up into several files based on content

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a log file that I would like to break up into several files

Table of Contents

```
*** Configuration Database
*** Logs
*** Configuration Logs
*** Query Logs
    .
    .
    and so on
```

The issue is, the titles of the section appear again in the body with the appropriate data or logs between the sections, so I’d have to search for the second instance of each title, and copy the data up to the second instance of the next title.

Body

```
*** Configuration Database
    (Data/Logs)

*** Logs
    (Data/Logs)

*** Configuration Logs
    (Data/Logs)

*** Query Logs
    (Data/Logs)
```

I’d basically like to take the debug text file, run a script against it, and have it break the file into many text files, one for each section in the Table of Contents, keeping the original intact. So I would basically have debug.txt, Configuration Database.txt, Logs.txt, etc, each having all the data in each section, up to when the new section starts. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is a little over my head :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk '/^[*][*][*] /{ if ($0 in seen) fname=$0; else seen[$0];} fname{print>fname}' file
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly reads a file line by line.  For each line read, we do the following:

- `/^[*][*][*] /{ if ($0 in seen) fname=$0; else seen[$0];}`

  For any line that begins with three stars and a space, we check to see if we have seen that line before.  If we have, we set `fname` to that line.  Otherwise, we update the associative array `seen` to indicate that we have seen this line once.
- `fname{print>fname}`

  If `fname` is a non-empty value, then write the current line to the file named `fname`.